# I have 2 pieces of script that work when running as separate macros, but not as a single macro

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Macro #1 includes all lines and is the macro I cannot get to work.

Macro #2 is the first section of Macro #1, which works on its own. This section inserts the current date and time into cell C3.

Macro #3 is the second section of Macro #1, which works on its own too. This section copies the formula from cell C3 and pastes it back into cell C3 as the values only.

If macros #2 & #3 work on their own, why wont they work when combined as shown in macro #1?

Using Google App Script for Google Sheets. Thanks.

Macro #1:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Puts current date/time in cell C2:

spreadsheet.getRange(2, 3).setFormula("=NOW()");

//Copies the date and pastes it as value (rather than a formula, so that it does not continue to update):

spreadsheet.getRange(2, 3).activate()

spreadsheet.getRange(2, 3).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

Macro #2:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Puts current date/time in cell C2:

spreadsheet.getRange(2, 3).setFormula("=NOW()");
```

Macro #3:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Copies the date and pastes it as value (rather than a formula, so that it does not continue to update):

spreadsheet.getRange(2, 3).activate()

spreadsheet.getRange(2, 3).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work what do you mean, is there an error? is there nothing happening? Also, how are you running these, from the GAS editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function myfunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(2,3).setFormula("=NOW()").activate();
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  sh.getRange(2,3).copyTo(sh.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
}
```

[SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush())

When you run them one at a time then all calculations are completed and the spreadsheet is updated properly.  However, when run in the same script that may not be the case and so SpreadsheetApp.flush() completes all calculations and updates the spreadsheet before continuing on.  This is sometimes important in webapps that depend upon cell functions to return results after providing data from form submission.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I ask - is there a particular reason you created both variables ss and sh instead of just creating and using the variable sh only? I am completely new to google script and was just curious why you created both if only one of them was used.

Comment: After writing a lot of script I find that using intermediate variables for things like that can be useful as the script grows.  So I have certain patterns that I tend to repeat over and over.